# Is there a Driver for the Thinkpad E14 Gen 4 fingerprint reader? (10a5:9800)

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I got a Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen 4 with a fingerprint reader. When trying to set it up I get

```
$ fprintd-enroll
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
```

My Hardware:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 10a5:9800 FPC FPC Sensor Controller L:0001 FW:16.26.23.14
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:2146 Acer, Inc Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I guess the driver is missing. Does someone know if one does exist? The Lenovo support page of course only has windows drivers

Cheers

Edit: I'm running pop os 22.04 with Linux 5.19.0

Comment: It would be helpful to know the version of Ubuntu and the kernel version being used. It could be as simple as a newer kernel.

Comment: We do not support PopOS! Only official Ubuntu. Please use https://unix.stackexchange.com/  More likely it is switched off in BIOS. https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html has no 10a5 listed so you might need to ask for support from fprintd maintainer

Comment: Hey. this might be a bit out of the way but I was thinking of getting the same laptop and was wondering if the AMD version is worth getting for long run. This comment might get deleted but just wanted to know. If i can have a chat with you somewhere else would be cool to make up my mind.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/1965931 Looking a this thread for answers myself

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as I understand now from the [Linux hardware database for this device](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:10a5-9800), there are no drivers for this fingerprint scanner model.